# Proof: All functions in $L^2[0,1]$ are in $L^1[0,1]$

Tags: solution-verification, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

I would like to know if my demonstration of all functions in $L^2[0,1]$ are in $L^1[0,1]$?

- $\forall f\in L^2[0,1] $ we can split $f$ in two differents spaces:
  $A=\left \{0\leq x\leq 1:|f(x)|>1) \right \}$ and $\textrm{no}A=\left \{0\leq x\leq 1:0\leq |f(x)|\leq 1  \right \}$
  (Of course $A \cup \textrm{no}A=[0,1]$.)
- We know too that $y^2>|y|$ iff $|y|>1$. So:

  1. $ \int_{\textrm{no}A}|f(x)|\mathrm{d}x \leq \int_{0}^{1}1\mathrm{d}x=1<\infty $
  2. $\infty>\int_{0}^{1}f^2(x)\mathrm{d}x\ge\int_{A}f^2(x)\mathrm{d}x> \int_{A}^{}|f(x)|\mathrm{d}x$
- So by (1)+(2): $ \int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|\mathrm{d}x = \int_{\textrm{no}A}|f(x)|\mathrm{d}x+\int_{A}|f(x)|\mathrm{d}x < \infty$ so by definition $f$ is in  $L^1[0,1]$ too.

Is it correct?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks correct to me.

Comment: Yes it's correct. As Gandalf says, however, this can be seen more simply by using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: CSI is standard for this problem but your result is also elegant. You can remove the inequality $\int_{n o A} f^{2}(x) d x \leq \int_{n o A}|f(x)| d x$ too to make it a little less verbose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overthinking albeit in a much elegant way.

Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. You have that $\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}\in L^{p}[0,1]\,, \forall p\geq 0$ . Let $f\in L^{2}[0,1]$

then $\int_{[0,1]}|f\cdot \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}|\,d\lambda\leq \sqrt{\int_{[0,1]}|f|^{2}\,d\lambda}\cdot\sqrt{1} <\infty$ as $f\in L^{2}[0,1]$.

Comment: I disagree about overcomplicating. His line of proof works more generally to show that $L^p[0,1] \subset L^q[0,1]$ for $0<q<p<\infty$.

Comment: In fact, if $f \in L^p([0,1])$ and $0<q<p<\infty$, then $\int_{[0,1]} |f|^{q} = \int_{|f|\le 1} |f|^q + \int_{|f|> 1} |f|^q \le \int_{|f|\le 1} 1 + \int_{|f|> 1} |f|^p \le 1 + \int_{[0,1]} |f|^p  < \infty$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems to me indeed shorter, but i have still very little knowledge in measure theory.

Comment: @X0-user-0X Don't worry....it seems you have a fine intuition . Once you learn Holder and Minkowski inequalities you will be even stronger . As Bob says in the comment. Your method is actually far more general and can prove for $0<p<q \leq \infty$. Which the Holder inequality cannot. Holder can only do it for $1\leq p<q\leq\infty$.

Comment: @Bob maybe overcomplicating is the wrong word. I have changed it .

Comment: @X0-user-0X I like your proof. Of course the proof becomes shorter if you use a non-trivial result like the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. You proved the result from scratch and as pointed out above, this works more generally to show that $$\forall 0<p<q<\infty:L^q(X,\Sigma,\mu)\subset L^p(X,\Sigma,\mu)$$ if the measure of $X$ w.r.t. $\mu$ is finite.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Hölder's inequality for non-negative measurable functions can be used to prove the result also for $0<q<p<\infty$. If $f \in L^p([0,1])$, we can leverage Hölder's inequality to obtain $\int_{[0,1]} |f|^q = \int_{[0,1]} (|f|^q \cdot 1) \le \big(\int_{[0,1]} ((|f|^q)^{\frac{p}{q}})\big)^{\frac{q}{p}} \cdot \big(\int_{[0,1]} 1^{\frac{p}{p-q}} \big) ^{\frac{p-q}{p}} = \big(\int_{[0,1]} |f|^p \big)^{\frac{q}{p}} <\infty$. However, despite being interesting as a proof of concept, I feel unease to teach a student that the right way to kill a fly is to shoot it with a bazooka.

Answer (score 0):

Your prove is nicer that the one below (to my point of view). But here an other solution.

Using Holder inequality we first identify $\frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{1} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{q}+ \frac{1}{r}$.
Holder inequality states that $\| f g \|_p \leq \| f \|_q \| g\|_r$ we take $g(x) = 1$ and thus we can write.
$\| f g \|_1 = \int_0 ^1 |f(x) \cdot 1| dx = \int_0 ^1 |f(x) \cdot 1| dx \leq \int_0 ^1 |f(x)|^2 dx \int_0 ^1 |1| dx < \infty$.
In other words $f(x) \in L^1 [0;1] $

---

More generally if $p \leq q$ we can still generalize your proof in order to prove that $f \in L^q (X; A ; \mu) \Rightarrow f \in L^p (X; A ; \mu) $ with $(X; A ; \mu)$ a finite measure space. by proceeding similarly.
1- If $p < q \Rightarrow \frac{1}{p} \geq \frac{1}{q}$ and that means $\exists r > 0$ s.t. $\frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r}$.
2- We apply the Holder inequality on $f(x), g(x)=1$ so we get:
$$ \|f \| _p= (\int(f(x) \cdot 1)^p d \mu)^{1/p} = \|f \cdot g \|_p \leq \| f \|_q \cdot \| g \|_r = (\int(f(x) \cdot 1)^q d \mu)^{1/q} (\int( 1)^r d \mu)^{1/r} < \infty $$